# Track down the [tracker]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

[tracker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tracker) has <s>130</s> 188 questions and no wiki.

It is used for questions about GPS tracking, web analytic, BitTorrent tracking, and more...

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**
   No, it is highly ambiguous.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**
   Most of the nuances are on-topic.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**
   With its current lack of precision, no. Questions tagged [tracker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tracker) can be about a vast array of technologies, none of which are closely related.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**
   I have not been able to identify a common context. But if you divide the tag into three or four bundles of questions, then mostly the same subjects show up.

Some questions were about a JavaScript library I already retagged ([meteor-tracker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meteor-tracker)).
Other suitables target tags would be [web-tracker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-tracker) or [gps-tracker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gps-tracker) but they do not exist.

Burn it?

[image]